# Event ID 1207 in Cluster Events Log once an hour

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, failovercluster, windows-server-2022

I have a two node, hyper-v failover cluster running windows server 2022. I'm getting this error every hour in the cluster events log, event id 1207:

"The computer object associated with the cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' could not be updated in domain during the Password change operation.

The text for the associated error code is: The parameter is incorrect.

The cluster identity may lack permissions required to update the object. Please work with your domain administrator to ensure that the cluster identity can update computer objects in the domain."

Checking google and chatai, results say to verify the cluster identity has correct permissions on the cluster object, which I have done.  I tried taking the server name cluster core resource offline and performing a repair. I receive an error that "the operation has failed. There was an error resetting the active directory password for 'Cluster Name'. Error Code: 0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect"**. I can bring the resource online.

Cluster validation passes.

I have a premium support ticket open with Microsoft but they haven't started troubleshooting and it's been two months. I've been told they are dealing with low staffing and a high-volume situation.

I'm using cluster shared volumes to store the VM files so rebuilding the cluster is the last thing I want to do.

I haven't found anything specifically related to the error "the parameter is incorrect". I'm stumped here.

Comment: I have a similar problem with some of our clusters... repairing the Cluster Core usually does nothing. Moving the resources between nodes does not help as well. Let me know when you find something.

Comment: Check the CNO in Active Directory. What is the modified date and password last changed date? What principal(s) have been granted the required permissions to the object?

Comment: Greg Askew whenChanged: 10/17/2023 pwdLastSet: 8/20/2023. The principals are the defaults set by Windows when I created the cluster.

Comment: David Trevor I will sing it from the mountaintop when I find a solution.

Comment: David Trevor After two months of errors in the cluster event log, the issue resolved itself this morning after restarting the nodes to troubleshoot a separate issue. SHRUG